# Editar modelo de User en Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

estoy practicando con Django y me gustaría saber si es posible editar el modelo de usuario para así agregar mas campos de los que tiene.
He intentado con OneToOneFile pero simplemente no funciona cuando hago mis migraciones

Aqui mi models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


class Patient(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, Null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='Nombre')                     
    sur_name = models.CharField(max_length=250,verbose_name='Apellidos')                 
    age = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Edad')                                 
    email = models.EmailField(default='null', verbose_name='Correo electronico')                   #Correo
    phone =  models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Telefono')                              
    register_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Fecha de registro')        
    update_info_date =models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Fecha de ultima actualización de datos')   #Fecha de actualización de datos

    class Meta():
        verbose_name = "Paciente"
        verbose_name_plural = "Pacientes"
        ordering = ['id']

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} {self.sur_name}"

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

Comment: ¿Qué significa "no funciona"?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes perzonalizar el modelo de usuario que viene por defecto hasta reemplazarlo en su totalidad.
Si solo quieres agregar mas campos tienes que heredar tu modelo de la clase AbstractUser.

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
        
class TuModelo(AbstractUser):
 cedula=models.CharField(max_length=11,null=False,blank=False) 
 username=models.CharField(max_length=25,null=False,blank=False,primary_key=True)  
    ...resto de atributos que quieres agregar
```

De esta forma obtienes esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me da errores de Reverse accessor para la migracion

Comment: Puede ser porque ya tenias tu base de datos hecha y a lo mejor te da conflictos migrando estos cambios; prueba con otra base de datos vacia; y para hacer las migraciones te recomiendo usar makemigrations, luego sqlmigrate tumodelo codigo y finalmente migrate o de que manera haces las migraciones ?

Comment: Si de hecho ya tenia el proyecto hecho jaja, lo hago exactamente como mencionas

Comment: Olvidaba que tienes que indicarle a Django cual es el modelo de usuario que debe usar, para esto en tu settings.py va lo siguiente: AUTH_USER_MODEL='nombreApp.TuModelo'

Comment: Okay ya anda, pero cuando empiezo con las migraciones me dice que no debo de dejar con null lo campos password y username, deberia hacer los campos password y username con sus valores default?

Comment: Cuando te sale ese mensaje te da la opción de establecer valores a esos campos, que es la opción 1, podrías hacer eso, o a tus Campos podrias ponerle que permita valores nulos.